# How to ENABLE touchpad tap-to-click while typing? Configuration keeps resetting every few seconds

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, synaptics

I want to (temporarily) disable the feature that disables touchpad tap-to-click while I am typing on my keyboard to be able to play games that require simultaneous interaction via mouse and keyboard without having to use a physical external mouse.

In other words, how can I use my touchpad to click things while pressing keys on the keyboard at the same time?

Everything I could find on Ask Ubuntu so far was the opposite, how to disable the touchpad while typing.

Some system info, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and `xinput` lists my touchpad as

```
SYN1B7F:00 06CB:7406 Touchpad
```

---

**Update:** What I tried after reading [this post on ElementaryOS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/how-to-not-disable-touchpad-while-typing).

First of all, the properties as listed by `xinput` and `synclient`:

```
$ xinput | grep Touchpad
⎜   ↳ SYN1B7F:00 06CB:7406 Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
$ xinput list-props 11 
Device 'SYN1B7F:00 06CB:7406 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (169):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (171): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (294): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (295):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (296):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (297):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (298):  49, 1187, 48, 850
    Synaptics Finger (299): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (300):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (301):   67
    Synaptics Tap Durations (302):  180, 100, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (303):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (304):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (305):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (306):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (307): 30, 30
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (308): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (309):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (310): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.130976, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (311):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (312):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (313):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (314): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (315):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (316): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (317):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (318): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (319):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (320): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (321):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (322): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (323):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (324): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (325):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (326):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (327):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (328):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (329): 12, 12
    Synaptics Area (330):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (331):  618, 0, 736, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (332): 7, 7
    Device Product ID (289):    1739, 29702
    Device Node (290):  "/dev/input/event12"

$ synclient 
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 49
    RightEdge               = 1187
    TopEdge                 = 48
    BottomEdge              = 850
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 67
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 30
    HorizScrollDelta        = 30
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.130976
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 2
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 7
    VertHysteresis          = 7
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 618
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 736
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

So from what I have read, `TouchpadOff` in `synclient` and `Synaptics Off (311)` in `xinput` should the interesting settings: 0="always enabled", 1="always disabled", 2="disabled while typing"

I tried to change it (only through `xinput` or only through `synclient` as well as through both together, several times):

```
$ xinput set-prop 11 311 0
$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

However, those settings were not persistent. Checking the value back *immediately* after setting it shows the change to 0, as expected:

```
$ xinput list-props 11 | grep Off
    Synaptics Off (311):    0
$ synclient | grep TouchpadOff
    TouchpadOff             = 0
```

But just a few seconds later, the values will reset back to 2 again automatically:

```
$ xinput list-props 11 | grep Off
    Synaptics Off (311):    2
$ synclient | grep TouchpadOff
    TouchpadOff             = 2
```

Note however that other settings like `synclient TapButton3=2`, which I use to enable 3-finger-tap as middle-click work fine and do not reset.

I have no idea what is happening here and why. Please help me to set this configuration correctly and persistently to be able to enable my touchpad even while typing.

Comment: I was having the same problem earlier but I found a solution that worked for me, hope it helps :) https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/how-to-not-disable-touchpad-while-typing

Comment: @Jompa I tried both answers in your linked post, but neither of them was able to change anything. I'll edit my question to explain what exactly happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make the touchpad always enabled for the current session, even while typing, by simply **killing the `syndaemon` process**. This automatically sets `TouchpadOff=0` in `synclient` too.

```
killall syndaemon
```

This will not prevent `syndaemon` from starting automatically again on the next reboot (or login?) though.

To disable the touchpad while typing again, you can therefore either reboot or just restart the `syndaemon` again by running

```
syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R -d
```

Again, this automatically takes care of the `TouchpadOff=2` setting in `synclient` by itself.